# How can I make these numbers center aligned?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

How can I make these numbers center aligned in the row? 
Also please suggest if you see something better to imporve it. 
(I also wonder if vertical lines look good or not or should I remove them)

EDIT: I'm sorry that I did not mention it clearly that the paper is two column format but the table is expanding on two columns combined instead of one column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table*}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{}
  \label{}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
                            \toprule
\textbf{No} &\textbf{C1}  &\textbf{C3}&\textbf{C4} \\\midrule
1    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

2    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: One possibility: change all image wrappers `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}` to `\begin{minipage}[c]{0.3\textwidth}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thanks, that wokrs. Do you have a solution for Overfull \hbox problem?

Comment: @hana - Yould replace `\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}` with `\begin{tabular}{@{} cccc @{}}`.

Comment: @Mico it still doesn't show all the rows for me.

Comment: If you want a table that spans multiple pages you'll have to use a longtable environment from the [longtable package](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable), or similar environment from a package with similar capabilities (e.g., longtblr from [tabularray](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en)).

Comment: @hana — Overfull rows and pages are two separate matters. You had asked in a comment how to fix the overfull hbox issue, and my Comment addressed that question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to remove the `[t]`, but there's a much simpler way to do it with `adjustbox`.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{A caption}
\label{label}

% local settings for the particular table
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% let TeX compute the horizontal space
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{\belowrulesep}
%%%

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}cccc}
\toprule
\textbf{No} &\textbf{C1}  &\textbf{C3}&\textbf{C4} \\\midrule
1
& \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
& \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
& \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\\
%\addlinespace
\midrule
2
& \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
& \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}
& \includegraphics[valign=c,width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c}
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

Note that the `\label` command you have inside `minipage` do essentially nothing else than referring to the same caption. Better just a global one. Also the `\hfill` commands did nothing.

By the way, vertical rules in tables are evil.

[image]

Comment: [`graphbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphbox) introduces a similar `valign` option and is perhaps lighter than `adjustbox`.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes use the following macro based on `\raisebox{}[][]{}`

```
\raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}[0.5\totalheight][0.5\totalheight]{<image>}
```

[image]

but it might need some adjustment for small images.

Explanation.

Each object in latex is within a [box](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes), an invisible container, including images. Each box has three properties: a baseline, height (vertical space above the baseline) and depth (vertical space below the baseline). AFAIK a baseline of an image is always set at its bottom. Since a baseline of texts is also set at the bottom, you will get this undesired effect.

In the macro above, `\raisebox{v-len}[new height][new depth]{content}` simply redefines a default box created by latex, hence the macro set a baseline of each image at its centre. If you look closely at the image, you will see a centre of each image is at the bottom of texts; this is where both baselines are. For very small images, the macro may need tuning. Also, `[new height]` and `[new depth]` do not have to add to `1\totalheight`, larger factors will add extra vertical space as total height will be increased. For instance, the code below will centre images and adds little vertical space

```
\newcommand\RI[1]{\raisebox{-0.48\totalheight}[0.55\totalheight][0.52\totalheight]{#1}}
```

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
% \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
% \usepackage{algorithmic}
% \usepackage{algorithm}
% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
% \usepackage{stfloats}
% \usepackage{url}
% \usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
% \usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
% \usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{parskip}
% \usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\RI[1]{\raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}[0.5\totalheight][0.5\totalheight]{#1}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table*}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{}
  \label{}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
                            \toprule
\textbf{No} &\textbf{C1}  &\textbf{C3}&\textbf{C4} \\\midrule
1    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \RI{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \RI{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \RI{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

2    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \RI{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \RI{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \RI{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `tabularray` (for `X[c,m]` columns) and  `adjustbox` (for `valign` and `\adjincludegraphics`) packages the code is short and simple:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[!t]
\caption{Table with images}
\label{tab:image}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}  
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\  
1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

- By `valign` is possible to move baseline of an image. With option `M` (or `v`) you can move their baseline to vertical center of image.
- Columns `X[c,m]` horizontal (`c` option) and vertical (`m` option) centers theirs contents.
- Using `\adjincludegraphics` instruction is possible set common option of image options: `valign=M`, and `width=\linewidth`.
  -Since by `valign` is moved images baselined to vertical center, now all cells contents in now is vertical centered.

[image]