# How can I make table expand over many pages?

Tags: tables, longtable, ieeetran

How can I make table expand over many pages? 
 I got some suggestion on longtable but couldn't make it work for this case.
The code below can only display the table in one page only. I need to expand the table over many pages.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

 \begin{table*}[!t]
  \centering
  \caption{}
  \label{}
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
                            \toprule
\textbf{No} &\textbf{C1}  &\textbf{C3}&\textbf{C4} \\\midrule
1    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

2    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule
3    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

4    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule
5    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

6    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule
7    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

8    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule
9    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

10    & \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

  \label{fig:first}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}

  \label{fig:second}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
&\begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}

  \label{fig:third}
\end{minipage}\\\midrule

\end{tabular}

\end{table*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Rmano can you tell me what is confusing? It's a table with many rows and you can think all rows' contents are same. 
I just checked the link you sent and tried it with my ieeetran class but I got an error saying that  longtable is not in 1-column mode.

Comment: I am not sure that longtable can work with two columns document.

Comment: @Rmano is there any solution to this problem? Would supertabular work?

Comment: @Rmano it's two column format but the table expands on both columns, does that make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your case, when document has two columns, you have two options, hot to insert long table in the document:

  - manually split table into two parts, each parts enclosed in `table*` float and for numbering of their captions use `\ContinuedFloat` command from `caption` package
  - before table change document format from two columns to one and return back two columns after table. At this you should be aware, that commands, which make this changes (`\onecolumn` and `twocolumn`) start new page. Consequently at this usual appears empty spaces before and after table (which as far as I know, cannot be removed by use of the `afterpage` package)

**First solution:**
Based is on my answer on your previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650086/how-can-i-make-these-numbers-center-aligned). For positioning tables at the bottom of the same page where is inserted and on the top of the next page is used `stfloats` package:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}  % <--- new
\usepackage{stfloats} % <--- new

\begin{document}
\lipsum
    \begin{table*}[b]
\caption{Table with images}
  \label{tab:image}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
3   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
    \begin{table*}[t]
    \ContinuedFloat
\caption{Table with images}
  \label{tab:image}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
4   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
5   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
6   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
7   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second solution:**
Use a long table, where are you need

- removed `table` float
- for table use of `longtblr` package instead of `tblr`
- for changes from one column to one column and back are used commands `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` respectively

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\onecolumn
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Table with images},
  label = {tab:image}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
3   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
4   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
5   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
6   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
7   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{longtblr}
\twocolumn
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**

- With your comments your question become unclear, what actually  is your problem.
- As far as I see, original version of answer solve all problems mentioned in your question.
- Site is not a forum. If you have new problem(s), on which you become aware after use of received answer, please ask new question. (Sub)question asked in comments are not (well) visible to others, which may help you better than me, so y this you exclude them to help you.
- Regarding your last request given in comments below:

  - vertical lines only in the first row:

```
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vline{1-Z}={1}{solid}, % <---
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
```

[image]

- smaller height of images, for example that their heights is only 22mm:

```
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, height=22mm, valign=M}
```

[image]

- for other options please consult packages documentations. They are part of your LaTeX installation and are also available on CTAN (use Google).

Comment: I'm sorry that the paper is two column format but I'm going to put the table like combining two columns so would that easy to modify?

Comment: @hana, in answer you have two possible solutions, how to do this. Choose one of them which you estimate that is the mots appropriate for you, There is no other possibilities. If no one suggested solution is easy to you, I don't (and can't) know.

Comment: Thanks,  the first one is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @hana, than you may consider to accept it ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to apply it to my real document and I'll accept it after that.

Comment: Is there any reason why the row height is so large and the third row doesn't show here? 
I'm trying to run in on overleaf but doesn't get the results that you showed.
https://www.docdroid.net/qeUgUN1/error-pdf#page=4

Comment: @hana, no. Row height is adopted to given images width so, that is preserved images `keepaspectratio`. I you like, you can distort it and define smaller images height or make smaller image width. All is up to you.

Comment: But I used exactly the same code you sent and the same image. I don't get the result like the images you sent. Is there some setting that you didn't update? This is the result I got: https://www.docdroid.net/qeUgUN1/error-pdf#page=4

Comment: Compiling my both MWE gives showed result (tested again). You apparently change something in givens MWE in your test. Or you have installed outdated packages. Try to upgrade your LaTeX installation to recent version.

Comment: It's a bit weird as I just copied and pasted it. I'm using overlea if that make any difference.

Comment: @hana, yes, this is main difference. Overleaf have outdated installation of  `tabularray`. Ask their help how to install recent version (2022B) to your local l  repository or install LaTeX on your computer.

Comment: I downloaded the package and uploaded it in overleaf and it works! One question, how can I change the height of the rows (assume that I may want to do that sometime in the future)?

Comment: how can I use vertical line for the first column only?

Comment: @hana, for all these questions you can find answers in  `adjustbox` and `tabularray` packages documentations. If all image heights are the same, write desired height of images into `\adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, height=<desired height>, valign=M}`, first row height you can changes with adding `ht=<desired height>`  to table preamble code row `row{1} = {...}`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question on the vertical column? Normally to add vertical lines for the first column I can set it like `|c|ccc` but your setting is new to me so I don't know how to modify it.

Comment: @hana, you may be right. If you have new problem(s), please ask new question. This site is not a forum ... I will edit answer ASAP

Comment: Sorry that you feel that. I just want to finish this in one post only. That is the last problem.