# How to add vertical line for the first column?

Tags: tables, tabularray

How can I add vertical line for the first column and first row as in the image? Normally I can do that by using this format `c|ccc` but this one is new to me and I don't know how to add it. 
I'm aware of [this document](https://ftp.harukasan.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabulary/tabulary.pdf) but it looks too complex for a beginner like me. 
 I searched for `vline` but didn't see where they mention how to do that.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}   % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}  % <--- new
\usepackage{stfloats} % <--- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[b]
\caption{Table with images}
  \label{tab:image}
    \adjustboxset{width=\linewidth, valign=M}
\begin{tblr}{hlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
No  &   C1  &   C3  &   C4  \\
1   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
2   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
3   & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-a}
            & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-b}
                    & \adjincludegraphics{example-image-c}  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on addendum on my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650091/how-can-i-make-table-expand-over-many-pages/650322#650322) on oy your previous question. Table preamble should be:

```
\begin{tblr}{hlines, 
                vline{2}=solid,         % <---
                vline{3-Y}={1}{solid},  % <---
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec= {c *{3}{X[c,m]} },
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             rowsep = 3pt,
             }
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any resource that explains these mysterious things like `vline{3-Y}={1}{solid}` or `vline{1-Y}={1}{solid}`? Google search doesn't seem to return anything.

Comment: @hana, of course it is. As I mentioned in one of my comments on your previous question: package documentation. It is concise, clear and with lot of examples. Documentation is part of part of your package installation or you can find it on CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray?lang=en

Comment: Probably I checked the wrong package.